# MS Access report parameter value

Tags: ms-access-2010

How i can open a MS Access report without giving any parameter value? I do not want dialagoue box enter the parameter value, when i click on report button. I did not put any parameter value in any query and any form regarding to this report.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Generally this means that your report has a field where its **Control Source** does not exist in the Report **Record Source**.   Check the the parameter value being requested.  It's quite possible that you just mis-keyed something in one of those two places..